# Self Joining A table

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to run a query that selects all of the users from the users table and joins itself because I would like to select who it was that created the user. For some reason I'm getting the same value I do for first_name and last_name in the creator as the same user which isn't true necessarily.

```
user_Id, username, first_name, last_name, creator_id

1, ksmith, Kevin, Smith, 1
2, wscott, Will, Scott, 1
3, sjones, Steve, Jones, 1
4, twilliams, Tom, Williams, 4
```

```
public function get_with_creator()
{
    $this->db->select('users.user_id');
    $this->db->select('users.username');
    $this->db->select('users.first_name');
    $this->db->select('users.last_name');
    $this->db->select('users.created_at');
    $this->db->select('users.updated_at');
    $this->db->select("CONCAT(creator.first_name, ' ', creator.last_name) AS creator_name", FALSE); 
    $this->db->from($this->_table); 
    $this->db->join('users AS creator', 'users.user_id = creator.user_id', 'inner');
    return $this->db->get()->result();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are joining the table(s) on `users.user_id = creator.user_id`.  So, it returns the same name for each field, because you are joining the same row.

You need to join on `users.creator_id = creator.user_id`.

DEMO: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e1309/2

Comment: Kudos for providing a SqlFiddle example

Comment: @TravisO: I love me some SQL Fiddle :-D

Answer (score 2):

```
$this->db->join('users AS creator', 'users.creator_id = creator.user_id ', 'inner');
```

Comment: Other way around `users.creator_id = creator.user_id` :-)